# How to keep original URL with HAProxy redirect option?

Tags: haproxy

I just setup HAProxy for my home LB. Let say my HAProxy server is myhaproxy.
I am expecting the URL using myhaproxy instead of backend servers server1.local or server2.local

When I am using this config. I encountered 404 not found error because the backends redirect to different site for login if the login session not found

```
frontend myfrontends
  bind *:80
  bind *:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/certs/
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  default_backend mybackends_https

backend mybackends_https
  balance roundrobin
  server server1 server1.local:443 check ssl verify none
  server server2 server2.local:443 check ssl verify none
```

This config working fine but the url changed from myhaproxy to server1.local or server2.local

```
backend mybackends_https
  balance roundrobin
  server server1 server1.local:443 redir https_server1.local check ssl verify none
  server server2 server2.local:443 redir https_server2.local check ssl verify none
```

I tried this config to keep the url https_myhaproxy. But I don't know how to set up header correctly for 2 or more backend servers because I am not sure which backend will selected by HAProxy

```
backend mybackends_https
  balance roundrobin
  http-request set-header Host server1.local
  server server1 server1.local:443 check ssl verify none
```

Is there any option like this for haproxy 2.7.8?

```
backend mybackends_https
  balance roundrobin
  server server1 server1.local:443 set-header Host server1.local check ssl verify none
  server server2 server2.local:443 set-header Host server2.local check ssl verify none
```

Thanks

https:// changed to https_ to bypass spam detection